# LINQ to SQL Basic question - table relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, relationship

I'm playing with an image gallery in ASP.NET MVC, and trying to get my head around LINQ to SQL at the same time.  I have 3 tables to hold image gallery data, with a many-many relationship through a link table.  These are :

> Gallery
>   (Id, Name, Description)
>
> Image
>   (Id, Title, Description, FileName)
>
> GalleryImage
>   (GalleryId, ImageId)

GalleryImage has FK relationships set up to the other two tables.

I want to be able to load my galleries, and display the images associated with each one, as well as have the ability to display a single image and list the galleries with which it is associated.  Since I'm new to Linq to SQL, I don't know how to do this.  Can anyone guide me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: create the associations between the tables.  You'll know this is done properly when

- class Gallery has property GalleryImages
- class GalleryImage has property Gallery and Image (note, singular)
- class Image has property GalleryImages.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629295.aspx

Step 2: To get a list of galleries:

```
using (CustomDataContext myDC = new CustomDataContext)
{
  List<Gallery> result = myDC.Galleries.ToList();
}
```

Step 3: then the user clicks on a gallery and you want its images:

```
using (CustomDataContext myDC = new CustomDataContext)
{
  List<Image> result = myDC.Galleries
    .Where(g => g.Id = selectedGallery.Id);
    .SelectMany(g => g.GalleryImages)
    .Select(gi => gi.Image)
    .ToList()
}
```

Step 4: Then the user clicks on an image and you want its galleries:

```
using (CustomDataContext myDC = new CustomDataContext)
{
  List<Gallery> result = myDC.Images
    .Where(i => i.Id = selectedImage.Id);
    .SelectMany(i => i.GalleryImages)
    .Select(gi => gi.Galleries)
    .ToList()
}
```

---

If you just want to load the whole database, do this:

```
using (CustomDataContext myDC = new CustomDataContext)
{
  DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
  dlo.LoadWith<Gallery>(g => g.GalleryImages);
  dlo.LoadWith<GalleryImage>(gi => gi.Image);
  myDC.LoadOptions = dlo;

  List<Gallery> result = myDC.Galleries.ToList();
}
```

After doing that, the whole object graph will be loaded and connected for your use.

Comment: Thanks.  I must be doing something very basic wrong, but can't for the life of me see what it is.  My DB tables have the relationships defined, my dbml diagram shows those relationships, and yet my entities don't have to expected properties.

Comment: Check the types of the properties involved. Look out for relating strings to ints, or ints to int?s.  Also make sure there are primary keys in the dbml.  LinqToSql can't track object identity (or make relational properties and object graphs) without those primary keys.

Comment: That was it.  My relation table didn't have keys set up - for some reason I assumed it didn't need them, only FKs.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Gallery.GalleryImages<GalleryImage>
```

You should be able to access your GalleryImage objects through that, and then on each GalleryImage you can call:

```
GalleryImage.Image
```

This assumes the relationships are represented in the DBML designer?

Comment: Thanks - The relationships are present in the DBML designer, but the GalleryImages property doesn't come up in IntelliSense.  I'm not sure I've created the DMBL correctly - I dragged the tables onto the design surface, and all appeared to be OK, but when I load the galleries (`from Gallery in db.Galleries select Gallery;`), I only get the gallery parent items.  Is that the wrong way to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access all this through your DataContext object.

Have a look in the generated c# file for your dbml and look for EntitySet collections marked with an Association attribute - there should be one in Gallary and Image, and 2 in GallaryImage.  If the dbml is generated correctly, you should be able to do something like the following -

Off the top of my head, i'm pretty sure that the design surface will name the plural of Gallery as Gallerys instead of Galleries, so it's not a typo -

```
DataConext dc = new GalleryDataConext();
foreach (Gallery g in dc.Gallerys)
{
  Console.Writeline("gallery id " + g.Id.ToString());
  foreach(GalleryImage gi in g.GalleryImages)
   {
      Console.Writeline("galleryimage id " + gi.Id.ToString());
      foreach(Image i in gi)
       {
         Console.Writeline("image id " + i.Id.ToString());
       }
   }
```

Even without the associations, the following should work -

```
int GalID = 1;
GalleryDataConext dc = new GalleryDataConext()
var pics = from g in dc.Gallary
           join gi in dc.GallaryImages on g.Id equals gi.GallaryId
           join i in dc.Images on gi.ImageId equals i.Id
           where g.Id = GalID
           select i;
```

To get gallaries from a pic id, you'd do -

```
int PicID = 1;
var gals = from g in dc.Gallary
           join gi in dc.GallaryImages on g.Id equals gi.GallaryId
           join i in dc.Images on gi.ImageId equals i.Id
           where i.Id = PicID
           select g;
```

The above will return you an `IQueryable<Gallary>` and will do the sql query when you enumerate over it.

Comment: It seems that my generated code does have the Associations you talk about, but I do not have access to them within my code.  It seems that the generated Gallery entity just doesn't contain a collection of GalleryImage objects.  I've even tried re-creating the entities to see if I did anything stupid first time round, but no joy.  
I've upvoted for the final 2 examples, although I had hoped not to have to go down the explicit route to get them.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create relationships among the tables.  if you are sure you have created the relationships then may be child or parent properties of classes may be set to internet they should be public